# React Native mixing style PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just recently started using React Native and trying my best to be a good little developer I'm defining the `propTypes` for my components.  However there is one thing that irks me about this process, which is the `style` prop type doesn't seem to be "composable" in any way.

---

For example, I want to create a `Divider` component that essentially consists of a `View` with a flat `backgroundColor` and a `width`/`height` set to the value of a `thickness` property; depending upon it's orientation.

When defining the `propTypes` for the `Divider` component I use the `View.propTypes` as I've seen people on the internet recommend, only I would like to use `color` instead of `backgroundColor` to specify the color of the divider. `View.propTypes.style` doesn't have a `color` property, and it doesn't seem possible to extend/compose the built-in `style` prop type.

Has anyone run into similar problems and have a decent remedy/workaround?

---

Another slightly different but related example: lets say I want to develop a `TextField` component which wraps `TextInput` and provides all of it's styling options plus an `icon` prop which will render the specified icon "inside" and to the left of the `TextField` the JSX might look something like this:

```
render() {
    const {
        icon,
        style,   // how to efficiently spread this across View and TextInput?
        ...props
    } = this.props;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {icon()}
            <TextInput ... />
        </View>
    );
}
```

I would like the spread the `style` supplied across the `View` and `TextInput` components where relevant (e.g. the `backgroundColor` property should be applied to the `View` component not the `TextInput`, likewise the color property should be applied to the `TextInput` component).

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a custom component, I don't think it is a good idea to have things mixed. My suggestions:

(1) if you really want someone to be able to pass in "style" as written, choose one and only one component where that style prop will spread to (e.g. choose the View and make it clear it should only be style props relevant to a view). Then, you could accept another custom prop that would define the style for the TextInput:

```
<View {...props.style} />
  <TextInput {...props.textInputStyle} />
  {/* ... */}
```

(2) Define custom props one by one on your component that will modify its style. For e.g. `<YourComponent color="white" backgroundColor="red" />` would mean you would use `props.color` to define the text component's color and `props.backgroundColor` would take care of the view component's background:

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor, ... }} />
  <Text style={{ color: props.color, ... }} />
  {/* ... */}
```

Remember that it is your custom component and you can accept any props, with any name! The implementation is up to you; internally, you should follow the basic component prop names -- but from without, your own custom component can be used in any way you'd like!

Comment: (1) I see a lot of component vendors taking this approach, IMO it's a pretty weak solution. I could understand doing this sort of thing for a `ListView` like component why `style` represents the container and `itemContainerStyle` represents the items but for a `TextField` this approach feels wrong.

Comment: (2) Again, I've seen this a fair amount already and it's undesirable because now we have styling information coming from two separate sources, where does it end? also for props like color, React Native doesn't expose `ColorPropTypes`, meaning we must resort to using something like `PropTypes.string`, `PropTypes.any` or some third party solution.

Comment: scratch that last comment about `ColorPropType` seemingly this is provided.